# How do I alias the result of a JOIN in MariaDB?

Tags: sql, select, mariadb

I have the following SQL `SELECT` statement that aliases the result of a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT tx.K,tx.J,tx.t   
FROM (
    J1_TBL CROSS JOIN J2_TBL
) AS tx 
ORDER BY tx.K,tx.J,tx.t
```

This works fine on PostgreSQL and DB2 LUW, but fails on MariaDB 10.5 with

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'AS tx ORDER BY tx.K,tx.J,tx.t' at line 1

So how do I alias the result of the `CROSS JOIN` in MariaDB?

Comment: Could you please try FROM (J1_TBL CROSS JOIN J2_TBL) tx ORDER BY tx.K,tx.J,tx.t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I alias the result of a JOIN

Make a working query. Wrap it in parenthesis.

```
SELECT
    tx.K, tx.J, tx.t   
FROM (
    SELECT
        J1_TBL.K, J2_TBL.J, J2_TBL.t
    FROM
        J1_TBL CROSS JOIN J2_TBL
) AS tx 
ORDER BY
    tx.K,tx.J,tx.t
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solution worked fine in MariaDB 10.5.

Comment: @GeoffAlexander It's standard SQL, it will work fine in any relational database.